# What's the connection between gettable, settable and stored property, computed property

Tags: swift, properties

I don't think I'm crystal clear on the connection between **gettable**, **settable** and **stored property** and **computed property**.

Can I say that the **gettable** is somehow related to **stored property** and **settable** is somehow related to **computed property**

Thanks so much for your time and help for a beginner like me

Comment: I think you are confused. Stored properties and computed properties are either settable, gettable, or both. Stored properties means it has a value, like var i = 0. Computed means it is a variable that depends on other variables. Edit: give this a read if you havent already: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Comment: @Jared Thanks for the resource I'll read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Computed properties:**

- Are not really properties at all
- Do not have memory that stores their value
- Are methods that present themselves as properties
- Have a `get` and optional `set` method that can be overridden
- Can be gettable, settable, or both.
- Example usage:

  - Get a temperature in Celcius from a stored property that's stored in Kelvin
  - Get the area of a rectangle that's stored in a `width` and `height` stored property

**Stored properties:**

- Are just like regular variables in other languages
- Have memory that stores their value
- Have a `willSet(_:)` and `didSet(_:)` method that can be overriden
- Can always be read, but can be read only.
- Example usage:

  - Store a temperature in Kelvin
  - Store a `width` and a `height` of a rectangle

Comment: Thanks for the explanation in the compare way.

Comment: @fpg1503 False: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259

Comment: @AMomchilov your link proves my point. They are computed so they can't be settable. They're either only gettable or both gettable and settable. What's the point of having a settable computed property that's not gettable?

Comment: Oh you mean they can't be *exclusively* settable. That's a big difference. I've updated my answer.